# d3: How to calculate delta-y correctly in a drag and drop?

Tags: d3.js

Looking at the [following d3 snippet](http://tributary.io/inlet/1ceb133640c560003200) and if you try dragging any circle up or down and thus, resizing the stacked bar elements you will notice that the cursor goes either faster or slower than the edge being resized actually the bars to the left-most are slower than the bars to the right-most... why is that? and how can be fixed?

The drag behavior is defined from line #110

```
var drag2 = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("drag", function(d) {
  var datum = data[d.group];
  var dy = d3.event.dy * 0.3; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here is scaled down
  if(d.i == 0) {              // but no matter what weight I put here   
    datum.bars[0].y1 -= dy;   // it will always be too fast or too slow .. 
    datum.bars[1].y0 -= dy;
  } else {
     datum.bars[1].y1 -= dy;
    datum.bars[2].y0 -= dy;
  }
  d.y -= dy;

  render(rects)
})
```

Basically the affecting line is 113 `var dy = d3.event.dy * 0.3;` here the `event.dy` is scaled down by 0.3 but why? I have played with that weight but no value seem to keep the edge being dragged and the cursor equal.

**UDPATE** This other example [How can I click to add or drag in D3?](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/da37B/) shows that a correct way to calculate is using `transform/translate` but these are attributes of an element and in my OP the affected target is the data itself and not a visual element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an inverse scale to calculate the `dy`, like so:

```
var drag2 = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on("drag", function(d) {
    var datum = data[d.group];

    y.domain([d.total, 0]);
    var dy = y.invert(d3.event.dy);

    // ...
});
```

Since this is just a linear scale you could also do it like this:

```
var dy = d3.event.dy * d.total / height;
```